# How to sort a column in an excel sheet which is made of formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet containing two columns and up to 1000 rows. Column 1 (Column A) contains name of items and Column 2 (Column B) is a drop down menu which mentions the item is "available" or "not available" which I will set manually everyday depending on item's availability.
I create a new column (Column F)which is having values of those cells in column A which is "not available". I have set a formula like this F2 = (IF(B2="not available",A2,"")).
After this operation,I want to sort column F only by values,which I was not able to do it.
is it possible using VBA code or by by excel formula itself?
A sample excel sheet is attached here:[image: Sample Sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some ideas from another site and worked on this code. This works absolutely fine .

```
Sub Call_Me_Unservieceable()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim i As Long
   Dim Lastrow As Long
   Dim Lastrowa As Long
   Range("F2:F30").Clear 
   Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Lastrowa = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To Lastrowa
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "Unserviceable" Then
            Cells(Lastrow, 6).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
            Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
        End If
    Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `=ROWS(F$1:F1)-COUNTBLANK(F$1:F1)` in G1, and `=IFERROR(INDEX(F:F,MATCH(ROW()-1,G:G,0)),"")` in H1, then drag downwards.

Done. Result is in Column H.

Idea : Count non-empty cells in column F using `ROWS()` - `COUNTBLANK()`. Then use Column H row() as reference to load column F values. Loading is done using index match method https://exceljet.net/index-and-match .

Please share if it works/not.

Comment: p._phidot_ I am getting #VALUE! in column G and no data in Coumn H .My data contains alphanumeric and special characters.That may be one reason.

Comment: Does " to sort column F only by values" can be done by just removing the empty rows?

Comment: If you are using excel 356 you may use the `SORT()` function https://exceljet.net/formula/sort-by-one-column (which I cannot test).

Comment: column F contains some alphanumeric cells and empty cells. If I am able to shift the empty cells down and keep all the non empty cells in the top i.e from F2 . That output is also fine.Once again column F values changes daily as per non availability.

Comment: I have attached a sample sheet in the question above the formula  =ROWS(F$2:F2)-COUNTBLANK(F$2:F2) is not yielding any results .I want to sort column "F" i.e get the non empty cells in the column to the top.

Comment: 1 formula is in G1, another one in H1 .. then (select both) and drag both downwards..

Comment: the result will be in column H, not F.

Comment: Since you had shared how your data looks like.. I think you can get what you need without any formula.. do [ Select column F > Data > Filter >(on the selection triangle) Unselect blank ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233736/discussion-between-kumara-guru-and-p-phidot).

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using Tables in Excel, you don't need a formula to achieve what you need. Just convert your data in  Column 1 (Column A) and Column 2 (Column B) into a Table then use the Filter button to Filter Column B by "not available". This way you do not need any formula and there will be no empty cells that need to be sorted.

But if you don't want to create a Table and what you need is to have the list of "not available" items in a separate column (Column F), then you can try this code in a regular code Module:

```
Sub NASort()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("F:F").ClearContents

Dim Serviceability As Range
Dim cel As Range
                  
Set Serviceability = Range(Range("B1"), Range("").End(xlDown))

For Each cel In Serviceability.Cells
Dim lastF As Range
Set lastF = Range("F:F").Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
If cel.Value = "Unserviceable" Then
cel.Offset(0, -1).Copy
lastF.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False
Else: cel.Offset(1, 0).Select

End If

Next cel

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Kindly let me know whether this is the solution you were looking for or not. In case it is, consider marking this answer as useful and accepted.

Comment: I am getting application oriented or object oriented error. I am new to VBA code. I have done like right click on the sheet and selected view code, then pasted the above code then ran it ,.  I am getting application oriented or object oriented error.  I have made few changes in the code , I have changed Availability to Serviceability and "B1" to "B2".

Comment: My need is whatever relevant cells are there in column A which is marked as Unserviceable in Column B ,Those values be copied to Column F . Everyday it changes

Comment: You do not need to change Availability to Serviceability but if you change it, make sure you change it everywhere it is used in the code (all 3 places). You do need to change "not available" to "Unserviceable" though. And if your data starts at cell B1, you don't need to change "B1" to "B2". I have updated the code to reflect these changes. Now, whenever you need to refresh the data in Column F just run the code.

Comment: And it seems you pasted the code in the Worksheet Module. You need to save it in a regular/standard Module. To do this, once you right click on the sheet and select view code, click on Insert → Module. Then paste the code in the new regular module window and run it.